# Python pymysql connection to mysql on Windows

Tags: python, html, mysql, sockets

my source

```
import pymysql
import socket
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', unix_socket='/tmp/mysql.sock', user='user', passwd=None, db='extractor')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM res")
for response in cur:
    print(response)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\python.py", line 20, in <module>
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', unix_socket='/tmp/mysql.sock', user='bitnami', passwd=None, db='extractor')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymysql\__init__.py", line 93, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 510, in __init__
    self._connect()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 658, in _connect
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AF_UNIX'
>>>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are under Windows, why are you trying to use the unix_socket parameter?

Try:

conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='user', passwd='', database='extractor')